# How to run a snapshot plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

When I attempt to run below maven plugin using this command :

> com.wordpress.pomfromjarmavenplugin:generate:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:generatepom

I get this error :

> Downloading:
>   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/wordpress/pomfromjarmavenplugin/generate/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/generate-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
>   [WARNING] The POM for
>   com.wordpress.pomfromjarmavenplugin:generate:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is
>   missing, no dependency information available [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 1.862s [INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 09 11:15:47 GMT
>   2012 [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Plugin
>   com.wordpress.pomfromjarmavenplugin:generate:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   com.wordpress.pomfromjarmavenplugin:generate:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could
>   not find artifact
>   com.wordpress.pomfromjarmavenplugin:generate:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in
>   apache.snapshots
>   (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/) -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Problem seems to be that all of the pom files have timestamps associated with them : 
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/wordpress/pomfromjarmavenplugin/generate/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

How can I run this plugin ? Do I need to wait until the plugin is released or somehow instruct maven to run the latest version of the snapshot ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines to your pom:

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>oss.sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Then your command should work:

```
mvn com.wordpress.pomfromjarmavenplugin:generate:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:generatepom
```

Or add these lines to your pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.wordpress.pomfromjarmavenplugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>generate</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then issue:

```
mvn generate:generatepom
```

Comment: but should'nt I be able to invoke the plugin directly from maven without having to download the src and install it on local repo ?

Comment: ok, thanks. Can I instruct maven to download a specific snapshot of the plugin as currently its trying to download a snapshot which does not have a timestamp? All of the snapshots on that repo (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/wordpress/pomfromjarmavenplugin/generate/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) have a timestamp associated with them.

Comment: @user701254 Updated my answer with a functional solution! :-)

Comment: This is such a gotcha when developing plugins! Would give you a load more up votes if I could, thank you!