# maven plugin: "Failed to read artifact descriptor for"

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

For my build process, I need two custom maven plugins ([see here](https://github.com/rweng/velocity-maven-plugin2)). It works fine when deploying it to my local maven repository with `mvn install`.

However, I need to make it accessible for other developer's in my team and integration testing.

I noticed that you could setup a light-weight maven repository on github so that's what I did for now: https://github.com/rweng/mvn-repo

This works fine for normal dependencies like ch.yax.yocto.yocto-server, however, it fails for my plugins with the message

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.arcanio.maven.plugin:velocity:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available**
[ERROR] Plugin com.arcanio.maven.plugin:velocity:0.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.arcanio.maven.plugin:velocity:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.arcanio.maven.plugin:velocity:pom:0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

I tried substituting the github url in my repositories section through `file:///`, Though I doubt the problem lies here. I also doubt that this is a proxy problems, as many users with the same error reported.

Is is possible that mvn install deploys s.th. different than my deployment command

```
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshot-repo::default::file:/Users/robin/Code/mvn-repo/ clean deploy
```

Thanks in advance for any hints how to solve this.

**EDIT**

I just moved the plugin from my local repository to the github repository and notice the following changes.

```
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/maven-metadata.xml
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/maven-metadata.xml.md5
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.md5
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-20130206.084855-1.jar
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-20130206.084855-1.jar.md5
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-20130206.084855-1.jar.sha1
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-20130206.084855-1.pom
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-20130206.084855-1.pom.md5
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-20130206.084855-1.pom.sha1
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/maven-metadata.xml
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/maven-metadata.xml.md5
 D com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
?? com/arcanio/maven/plugin/maven-metadata-local.xml
?? com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/_maven.repositories
?? com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-local.xml
?? com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
?? com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/0.1-SNAPSHOT/velocity-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
?? com/arcanio/maven/plugin/velocity/maven-metadata-local.xml
```

So `mvn install` really does generate something different. Does anyone know why? I thought `mvn install` was basically the same as `mvn deploy` but to the local repository.

**EDIT**

Using `mvn -DuniqueVersion=false` fixes the unique versions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920536/why-the-snapshot-name-always-has-date-in-its-jar-file-name-how-to-remove-it).

**EDIT**

`uniqueVersion=false` [does not work anymore with maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-NonuniqueSnapshotDeployments). So the problem stays the same, the timestamped versions are not found in the repository. I think I might be missing a artifactid-snapshot pom.

**SOLUTION**

Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307742/how-to-run-a-snapshot-plugin):

The repository must be added as pluginRepository:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>rweng-plugins</id>
        <url>https://github.com/rweng/mvn-repo/raw/master</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for such things is to install a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) in your company.

Comment: +1 on this.  And this answer give some of the big reasons for why not to use GitHub as repository: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22210816/395202